Can a single method be excluded from an ArchUnit class access rule?
I want to define an ArchUnit rule that prevents the use of the EntityManager class outside of my repository classes. I have one exception to this rule, a single call to entityManager.detach in com.myapp.EventService.
Currently my JUnit 5 rule looks like this:
    @ArchTest
    static final ArchRule onlyRepositoriesMayUseEntityManager = noClasses()
        .that().resideOutsideOfPackage("com.myapp.repository..")
        .and(are(not(equivalentTo(EventService.class))))
        .should().accessClassesThat().areAssignableTo(EntityManager.class);

But this will allow any method of EntityManager to be used in EventService. I would rather either of the following

Allow only the detach method to be used in EventService
Allow only the detach method to be used anywhere outside of the repositories


.should().accessTargetWhere(…
allows you to specify a DescribedPredicate for a JavaAccess (not to be confused with its AccessTarget  – cf. ArchUnit's domain model).
With that, a solution for your option 1 could be (using DescribedPredicate.describe):
@ArchTest
ArchRule onlyRepositoriesMayUseEntityManager = noClasses()
    .that().resideOutsideOfPackage("com.myapp.repository..")
    .should().accessTargetWhere(describe("owner is assignable to EntityManager", access ->
        access.getTargetOwner().isAssignableTo(EntityManager.class) &&
        !(access.getOriginOwner().isEquivalentTo(EventService.class) &&
          access.getTarget().getName().equals("detach"))
    ));


Thanks for your detailed reply. BTW, I noticed that you kindly replied to both this post and the GitHub issue. Please let me know if it's considered bad form to post the same question in both places and I'll stick to one or the other from now on.

You're welcome. I don't mind the duplication; maybe you reach different people here and there? I just want the same information linked in both places.
